# Symbols loaded errors when trying to compile in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a simple Hello World C++ program with Visual Studio 2012 and I'm getting a bunch of errors related to symbols not being loaded.

```
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Raphael\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Hello World\Debug\Hello World.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'
The program '[3668] Hello World.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I've checked the location on my local hard drive and each of the .dll files reside in that folder, so I'm not sure why it's unable to load them.

Comment: What you've posted are not errors, and are not coming from the compiler.

Comment: -1 Read what you've posted. There's no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing here is related to symbols *not* being loaded:

```
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

Visual Studio is going to run your program under the debugger. It loads debugging symbols...

```
'Hello World.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'
The program '[3668] Hello World.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

... successfully starts your program (which means that it was successfully compiled), and the program exits with code 0.

Comment: Well, I feel silly now. I'm used to seeing the output in a window instead of running the executable. Thanks.